# Regex - No Numbers Found

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible to check If no numbers were found in a string when using **Regex**?

so if I am doing this:

```
String temp;
String myText = "abcd";
temp = Regex.Match(myText, @"\d+").Value;
```

How do i check that no numbers were found?

Do i just do this:

```
if (temp = ""){
//code
}
```

Comment: You can do `if (Regex.IsMatch(myText, @"\d+"))`. Easy, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the better way to do it would be

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(stringToCheck, @"\d+"){
    // string has number
}
```

if you want to deal with no numbers found, then try like

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(stringToCheck, @"\d+"){
    // no numbers found
}
```

to find all the matches of number in a string

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matchs(stringToCheck, @"\d+");

foreach(Match match in matches){
    //Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I ruined your perfect reputation :P.

Comment: @Fuex - thnx for it !

Answer (score 1):

You don't get a match. If you had a match you'd have found a number somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a reverse match with a regex.

```
if ( !Regex.Match ( stringToCheck, "^[0-9]+$" ).Success ) {

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `IsMatch` and then **negate** it

```
if(!Regex.IsMatch(inp,".*\d.*"))//no number found
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Match temp;
String myText = "[0123456789]";
temp = Regex.Match(myText).Value;
bool NoDigits = !temp.Success;
```

Sorry for the original confusion in my answer.  Also, you can keep using the \d flag, I just like [0123456789] because it makes it stand out more in this simplistic case.

Comment: What do you do when you want to specify `[a-z]`, type them all out?

Comment: @weston No, but it's easy enough to run my finger across the keyboard and this code snippet is more for explaining the concept that using as few characters as possible (which should **never** be a goal for developers).

Comment: LOL (to running finger over keyboard comment)! No I'm not concerned about the code's length in this case, just code quality. I think it's bad practice to avoid the tools that are given to you just in order to dumb it down for someone. Give people some credit. Also the range (`[0-9]`) and digit (`\d`) implementations may well be more efficient, just think how each would be implemented compared to a character set implementation like yours.

Comment: Efficiency isn't something I considered.  I just assumed the implementation would convert the shorthand into the same value before actually running the regex, but that's actually something to consider now that you mention it.

Comment: BTW, this sparked some investigation on my part, with some surprising results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-less-efficient-than-0-9

Answer (score 0):

```
String myText = "abcd";

if (Regex.IsMatch(myText, "[0-9]+"))
{
    // there was a number
} else {
    // no numbers
}
```